# Dynamically update user selection using using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I need help on this code. I want to dynamically prohibit a user from adding  to cart if the requested stock item (Database) is less than his request (qty). Will appreciate, if I can know where I am wrong and probably someone correct it for me.

**HTML FORM**

```
<form action="cart.php?adm_id=<?php echo urlencode($patient["adm_id"]);?>" method="post" name="CartForm" target="_self">
<p>Product Name:<select name="prod_name" size="1" id="prod_name">
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<?php
while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
 ?>
<option value="<?php echo $line['prod_name'];?>"> <?php echo $line['prod_name'];?> </option>  
<?php } ?> 

</select></p>
<p>Quantity:<input  type="number" name="qty"   id="qty" size="30"  required="required"/></p>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Add to Cart" id="btn"/> | <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Cancel" />
```

**Ajax Code:**

```
<script src="javascript/jquery-2.0.3.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(ex) {
    //$('#stock').load('pharmacy_summary.php');
 $('#qty').change(function(){
var prod_name = $('#prod_name').val();
var qty= $('#qty').val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'confirmStock.php',
    data:{prod_name: prod_name, qty: qty},
    success: function(e){
        if(e == 'true'){
            /*if the quantity is greater than the stock*/
            alert('stock Item is lower to your request, reduce it');
            $('#btn').prop('disabled', true);
        }else{
            $('#btn').prop('disabled', false);
        }    }
})});    
});
</script>
```

**PHP/MYSQLI Code:(ConfirmStock.php)**

```
<?php require_once("/includes/db_connection.php");?> 
<?php require_once("/includes/functions.php");?> 
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['prod_name'])){

  $getProd = $_GET['prod_name']; 
  $getQty = $_GET['units'];

 global $connection;
  $val = "SELECT * FROM pharmacy_stock_tab WHERE prod_name='".$getProd."'";
   $conf = mysqli_query($connection,$val); 
   $fetchVal = mysqli_fetch_array($conf);
   $stock = $fetchVal['units']; 
   if($getQty>$stock){
    return $stock;
   }else{
   return  $stock;
   }

 }

?>
```

Comment: for one thing `MYSQL_ASSOC` needs to be `MYSQLI_ASSOC` - you're mixing APIs.

Comment: then in your `cart.php?adm_id` you're doing a GET method but there's nothing matching that, aside from mixing GET and POST. `if(isset($_GET['prod_name'])){` should probably be `if(isset($_GET['adm_id'])){`

Comment: What is not working in your code?

Comment: @Fred, thks, the cart.php?adm_id has been sent from the top. I only did not include it in the question. $patient= find_patients_by_id($_GET["adm_id"]); However, this is not the issue, as it is working fine for that aspect. Also, it should read isset prod_name and not adm_id. The reason is this: when a user select a prod_name, and proceed to select the qty, i want to be able to compare that qty with the total qty for that prod_name in the DB. if the selected qty is greater than the DB(total)qty, then trigger alert and disable btn add to cart, otherwise go successfully to add. Period

Comment: Ok. Well, someone has provided you with an answer below; *give it a whirl* ;-)

Comment: @ Semsem: what is not working is user is able to select more than the total qty of product from the DB with trigger alert and add to cart btn not working, which is not the desire.

Comment: @Fred, I have tried it, but still not working.....

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to `mysqli_query()`. Plus, some of my comments that I've already said.

Comment: @Fred, I have worked on it, but still the same issue oooo. Or can u give me a better way of confirming a selection field based on Database qty, without refreshing the page....

Answer (score 0):

You must change the way you send response and the way you handle the response. change the code in ConfirmStock.php 
change the return statements in following way

```
$result = array();
if($getQty>$stock){
   $result['success'] = 'true';
   $result['stock'] = $stock;
 }else{
$result['success'] = 'false';
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
die();
```

In Ajax success method

```
   success: function(response){

    if(response.success == 'true'){
        /*if the quantity is greater than the stock*/
        alert('stock Item is lower to your request, reduce it');
        $('#btn').prop('disabled', true);
    }else{
        $('#btn').prop('disabled', false);
    }    }
```

Comment: I am given it a try. but users are scaling through with more than the DB qty, to the point that the DB qty is now showing -value. any further assistance?

Comment: Any futher help, I want  a solution to this task, I have done what you suggested but did not work.

Comment: what response you got did you alert the response in success method like     alert(JSON.stringify(response));